# Amazon Product Advertising API - Check If Items In Cart Were Actually Purchased?

Tags: api, amazon-product-api

I'm using the `CartCreate operation` from `Amazon Product Advertising API 5.0` to add items to a remote shopping cart. In response, Amazon returns the `<PurchaseURL>` along with other details of items in cart such as CartId, Price etc.

Is it possible to programmatically determine whether the items in the remote shopping cart were actually purchased?

Thanks